# Kernel density tool does not produce an .asc output file

Tags: arcgis-10.3, file-formats, kernel-density

I have made a kernel density map in ArcGIS 10.3 and 10.5, but the output appears as an .aux file, not an .asc file (which I will need to use for occurrenceThinner). A folder appears also with a metadata file, and several .adf files. Why am I not getting a single .asc file with .aux, .ovr and .prj? I have run the tool before and got these files, but recently have only been getting the .aux file and folder.

Input is a csv of species occurrence in lat/long.

Paramaters:
Population field = NONE; Output cell size = 0.0041666666 (Trying to get a 500m square). GCS is WGS 1984; Area units = Square Kilometres; Output values = Densities; Method = Geodesic.

Output:
[image]

EDIT: I should say that the kas.asc was given to me by someone else as I couldn't produce an .asc...

Comment: Can you add more details about your input, screenshot of your output, which software you use, which parameters did you use?

Comment: ASCII is such an awful raster format that Esri doesn't consider it one. Plan to use GeoTIFF for all your data modelling and then you won't accidentally create old ArcInfo Grids.

Comment: Have provided more information @User2009

Answer (score 1):

You've already answered your own question, but for the benefit of future readers:

*"Why am I not getting a single .asc file with .aux, .ovr and .prj?"*

These extensions mean the output file format is [Esri GRID](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-grid-format.htm), which is what you get when specifying an out filename with no extension, `my_output`. (In most cases it's better to use Geotiff, `my_output.tif`.)

After generating the Kernel Density raster export to [Esri Ascii Grid](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-ascii-raster-format.htm) format using [Raster to Ascii](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-ascii.htm) tool.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the kernel raster to ascii produces an .asc file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136689)

Comment: How does it not? The Kernel tool produces a raster in ESRI grid format, which then when converted to an ascii file, produces an .asc file. This is the information I was looking for in the first place.

Comment: This, in fact, does not provide an answer! We are looking for answers with depth, not one liners or link-only. You do not provide any context to the what, why and how. For example, you could have provided an explanation on writing different formats using defined file extension(s), what happens when you do not designate one and how to export to a ArcGrid ASCII format.

Comment: Ok thanks @Jeffrey. I just felt this would have been sufficient for someone like me who had the exact same confusion and knew how to do the other steps (writing different formats, exporting to ascii format). Had I seen this answer myself, I would have tried it and found it to have answered my question. I guess I just assumed people looking here would already have done a little background research and found in more appropriate places information on how to use and create different file types...